# Node.JS constant for platform-specific new line?

Tags: node.js

Is there a constant available in Node.JS for a newline character that is specific to the platform the application is running on?

For example:

- Windows: `\r\n`
- *nix: `\n`

Comment: Why not simply use `\n` all the time?

Comment: @ThiefMaster, ... because I would like files written to line up with the standards for the platform in use.

Answer (score 293, accepted):

There is a constant [`os.EOL`](http://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_eol):

```
import { EOL } from "node:os";
```

or

```
const { EOL } = require("os");
```

`EOL` then has a value of `"\n"` on POSIX or `"\r\n"` on Windows.

Comment: new in : v0.7.8, use with care

Comment: or `const { EOL } = require('os');`

Comment: I amended to yours which is more modern @Not loved

Comment: These days, you can even get away with `import { EOL } from 'os'`, but I also recognize the answer was written in 2012 with comments/edits going to 2019

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is good for server-side only JavaScript with Node.js. If you have a package that serves both browser and server-side JavaScript then you want to support both:

```
const IS_WIN: boolean = typeof process !== 'undefined' && process.platform === 'win32';
const LINE_END: string = IS_WIN ? '\r\n' : '\n';
```