# How to convert javascript object to plain text so that while posting the data i can post simple text

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular5, nodemailer

I have a problem here i am making an ionic application with angular 5 and ionic v.2

I have a backend which helps me to trigger email on the click of a button but in that email i have to post data from the front end that is let say order summary with email. So this order summary i am posting it from front end.

I have a javascript object with key value pairs i want to post this javascript object as a plain text so that while the user reads his email the response should not be a json it should be a plain text only

example of object which is getting posted in api as body:

```
coalCredentials = {
"company_id": "hitachi09",
"company_name": "hitachi" ,
"country": "" ,
"current_stock" : "88",
"delivery_remarks":"yes",
"demand_stock":"66",
"expected_order_delivery":"2018-08-08",
"gar":"",
"gsv":"",
"nar":"",
"plant_address":"gachibowli",
"product_name":"coal",
"product_size":"",
"product_type":"petcoke",
"seal_check":"yesonseal",
"vessel_type":"huit"
}
```

so this is a json format of sending data. I want to send it as plain text so that result while sending appears to be

```
company_id: hitachi09
company_name: hitachi
country: 
current_stock :88
delivery_remarks:yes
demand_stock:66
expected_order_delivery:2018-08-08
gar:""
gsv:""
nar:""
plant_address:gachibowli
product_name:coal
product_size:""
product_type:petcoke
seal_check:yesonseal
vessel_type:huit
```

so please can someone helps what needs to be done so that email can look meaning full to the customer.

weather the change should be on the backend or on the front end

front end is in angular 5 and backend is in node.js

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```js
const coalCredentials = {
  "company_id": "hitachi09",
  "company_name": "hitachi",
  "country": "",
  "current_stock": "88",
  "delivery_remarks": "yes",
  "demand_stock": "66",
  "expected_order_delivery": "2018-08-08",
  "gar": "",
  "gsv": "",
  "nar": "",
  "plant_address": "gachibowli",
  "product_name": "coal",
  "product_size": "",
  "product_type": "petcoke",
  "seal_check": "yesonseal",
  "vessel_type": "huit"
};

const textFormat = Object.entries(coalCredentials)
  .map(([key, value]) => key + ':' + value)
  .join('\n');
  
console.log(textFormat);
```

Note: use `\r\n` instead of `\n` if you're on Windows, or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14063413/965834) if you need it platform-specific.

**Alternative version** which doesn't require `Object.entries` (which only exists since ES2017):

```js
const coalCredentials = {
  "company_id": "hitachi09",
  "company_name": "hitachi",
  "country": "",
  "current_stock": "88",
  "delivery_remarks": "yes",
  "demand_stock": "66",
  "expected_order_delivery": "2018-08-08",
  "gar": "",
  "gsv": "",
  "nar": "",
  "plant_address": "gachibowli",
  "product_name": "coal",
  "product_size": "",
  "product_type": "petcoke",
  "seal_check": "yesonseal",
  "vessel_type": "huit"
};

const textFormat = Object.keys(coalCredentials)
  .map(key => key + ':' + coalCredentials[key])
  .join('\n');
  
console.log(textFormat);
```

Comment: Hi when i am doing this it says entries does not exist on type ObjectConstructor

Comment: @MayankPurohit I just edited my post with an alternative version that shouldn't require ES2017 JS. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
let keyArr = Object.keys(coalCredentials);
let p = 0;
let final = "";
for(let x in coalCredentials){
  final += keyArr[p] + ":" + x + "\n";
  p++;
}
```

Then you can use the final string for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Object.keys` in ES6, hope it helps!

```js
var coalCredentials = {
  "company_id": "hitachi09",
  "company_name": "hitachi" ,
  "country": "" ,
  "current_stock" : "88",
  "delivery_remarks":"yes",
  "demand_stock":"66",
  "expected_order_delivery":"2018-08-08",
  "gar":"",
  "gsv":"",
  "nar":"",
  "plant_address":"gachibowli",
  "product_name":"coal",
  "product_size":"",
  "product_type":"petcoke",
  "seal_check":"yesonseal",
  "vessel_type":"huit"
}

var plainText = '';
var keyArray = Object.keys(coalCredentials)
var valueArray = Object.keys(coalCredentials).map(key => coalCredentials[key])

for(let i=0; i<keyArray.length; i++) {
    plainText = plainText + keyArray[i] + ': ' + valueArray[i] + '\n';
}

console.log(plainText)
```

Comment: [ts] Property 'values' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'. @Van goh

Comment: So sorry for that, for using ES7's `Object.values` in TS you might need `ES2017` in your `--lib` setting. 
btw I have fixed it just now, take a look, it should work. Cheers! ;)