# How to do a line break in fs text file for logging purposes

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I'm using fs module to log my node.js app, and I don't find on google how to do a linebreak with fs for a text file...

I've tried some fs.append with nothing in it and it just doesn't make anything.

Thanks in advance,
~TBD

EDIT : I'm using .txt file to enable fast log reading...

Comment: @t.niese Windows is `\r\n`.  Old, old Mac was `\r`.  In any case, you should use the `EOL` constant from `os`.  See also:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/14063413/362536

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be great to have some sample code to show for further help, but normally the code would look like this:

```
//Suggesting you are using ES6, if not, change all 'const' to 'var'

const fileSystem = require('fs');

//Change the data below, the path and data, but not the \n. There might be problems when using \n, if it occurs, consider changing it to \r.
fileSystem.writeFileSync('./path/to/your/file.txt', 'yourdata\n');
```

See: [\n or \r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761051/difference-between-n-and-r)