# Regex matching multiple returns & single returns in plain text file

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

Say I have the following text file:

```
Here is a line and some more and some more 
Here is a line
Here is a line
Here is a line

Here is a line
Here is a line
Here is a line
Here is a line
```

I would now like to first split this text file into its two paragraphs, and then also split each paragraph into each line.

**1)** I thought I could simply reg-ex match `\n\n` for paragraphs, and then afterwards do a `\n` for each line. But this doesn't seem to work? I am not sure why.

**2)** Also, I think in addition to `\n` there is also `\r` - will I need to cover this case too? Are there any other?

Comment: Please share your code, even though it does not work and tell us where it fails and what you expected.

Comment: Open your text file in a text editor that can display special characters \n and \r, for example Notepad++. Then you can see whether to check for \n\n or for \r\n\r\n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require('os').EOL` should return to you the newline separator for the platform (https://stackoverflow.com/a/14063413/6632736).

```js
const text =
`Here is a line and some more and some more 
Here is a line
Here is a line
Here is a line

Here is a line
Here is a line
Here is a line
Here is a line`

const { EOL } = require('os');
const EOL1 = new RegExp(EOL);
const EOL2 = new RegExp(EOL + EOL);

const splitter = text =>
    text.split(EOL2).map(text =>    // two newlines.
    text.split(EOL1)                // one neline.
);

console.log(splitter(text));
```

Comment: This works only if the text file came from a platform that uses the same line separator as the OS the code is running on.

Answer (score 0):

**This is a working solution.**

```js
const str = `Here is a line and some more and some more 
Here is a line
Here is a line
Here is a line

Here is a line
Here is a line
Here is a line
Here is a line`;
const para = str.split('\n\n');
const regLine = /((^|\n)[^\n]+)/g;
para.forEach((paraEach, ind) => {
  console.log('_______________');
  console.log(`paragraph ${ind} = `);
  while(arrM = regLine.exec(paraEach)) {
    console.log('line = ', arrM[1]);
  }
});
```